# Bug at loading URLs to images

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I think that I've found a bug in the add-on SDK. When I try to load a tab doing something like this:

```
             var t = tabs.open({
                 url: linkURL,
                 inBackground: true,
                 onReady: closeTab(this)                 
             });
```

And the URL is an image. The onReady event is never fired.

Is that the expected behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: You probably meant something like `onReady: function() { closeTab(this) }` - define a callback rather than call `closeTab` immediately.

Comment: I have a question with that, why is better this way you say? I mean, `closeTab` is the actual callback. I don't see why is better to define an anonymous function that invokes it. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Oh, may be this way I'm calling the function because I give explicitly the parameters.. It would be correct if I just give the closure of the function?

Comment: Yes, a callback has to be a function. You are calling a function and trying to use the result as the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this counts as a bug but you should probably [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK) to see what the developers think about it. The problem is that the SDK waits for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to recognize that the tab is ready - but Gecko doesn't fire this event for image documents. The SDK could [use a web progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener) instead, these work regardless of the document type.

Comment: +1: for giving a possible workaround to the developers! hahah

Comment: I could also implement a web progress listener instead of listening to the ready event, right? The `tab` is a `tabbrowser` object?

Comment: @Kits89: No, going from the SDK `tab` object to a DOM node is not possible, you can only work with the abstraction that the SDK gives you. You would have to get the browser window yourself and open a tab with the usual XUL methods, without using the `tabs` module.